# Alphabets and Numbers? : Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Now we all know how crazy Grandpa is when it comes to Math. He says to me:

"Use your imagination and tell me,

> **If 
>
>   Seven + L = Zero 
>
>   And 
>
>   Zero - C = One 
>
>   Then 
>
>   Three + I = ?**

I have no idea!”

Comment: Is the ** a formating error?

Comment: @PotatoLatte Maybe, maybe not :P

Comment: Well, since it got fixed, no?

Comment: It probably does not have to do with the numbers themselves, as they use the words instead of the numbers

Comment: It was fixed by me because I assumed this was the intention. If DEEM wishes to change it, they may roll it back.

Comment: H - Four + Five = ?  is another nice one.

Comment: @Keeta  very nice. Should have thought that one

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Based on DEEM’s hint, the answer is

> Eight.

I think this is because

> When you look at the digital number for 7, and add an L to the left of it, you get L7 which looks like a digital Zero. When you look at a digital Zero and remove a C from the left of it, you get a digital One. When you take a digital 3 and add an I to the left of it, you get a digital Eight.

Comment: Damn, I reached my daily voting limit (DVL).

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be

> One, also.

The function is

> $f(x) = (x+1) \pmod 2$, where $x$ is the result of the addition or subtraction when you convert the letters to Roman numerals.

So:

> For $x = \mbox{Seven}+L = 7+50=57$, $f(x) = (57+1) \pmod 2 = 0 = \rm Zero$. 
>  For $x = \text{Zero}-C = 0-100=-100$, $f(x) = (-100+1) \pmod 2 = 1 = \rm One$. 
>  For $x= \mathrm{Three} + I = 3+1 = 4$, $f(x) = (4+1) \pmod 2 = 1 = \rm One$.

Of course, the answer could also be

> Zero.

If the function was

> $f(x) = H(-x)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function, equal to 1 for $x\geq 0$ and 0 for $x<0$.

Then

> For $x = \mbox{Seven}+L = 7+50=57$, $f(x) = H(-57) = 0 = \rm Zero$. 
>  For $x = \text{Zero}-C = 0-100=-100$, $f(x) = H(-(-100)) = 1 = \rm One$. 
>  For $x= \mathrm{Three} + I = 3+1 = 4$, $f(x) = H(-4) = 0 = \rm Zero$.

Comment: Please note that there is no MATH tag on this @El-Guest

Comment: I have edited this post by carrying out the following actions: changed $mod2$ to $\pmod 2$ via the command `\pmod 2` and I also changed $this~font$ to $\rm \underline{this~font}$ with multiple commands like `\mbox` and `\text` etc (see which one you prefer). (The underline is not part of the actual font, but provides an emphasis.) Do you approve of this edit? :)

Comment: Yes, but I figured there was some lateral thinking involved in deriving this answer! Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Thank you, @user477343! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problemo! $(+1)$ :D

Comment: Think digital says Grandpa